# Give an combinatorial argument

Tags: proof-verification, combinatorial-proofs

I need to find the possible value of $R_i$ and prove it by giving combinatorial argument,  for following identity.

[image]

I was able to give an argument like this.

Consider **double counting**.

*Count number of ways to arrange $n$ labeled balls.*

**One way** of counting is permutation of all balls, which is $n!$.

**Second way**:

Calculate it by fixing positions of some of them and permute the rest such that none comes at it's original position.

Like choose $i$ balls from $n$ and fix them, find derangement of rest $n-i$ balls.

So in the equation we have $R_i$ is Derangement of  $i$ numbers.

Am i missing anything ? Is proof valid and correct ?

**If correct, I would love to read more elegant proof in answer. thank you.**

Comment: Nicely done. You will find your formula mentioned in the 2. Counting Derangements part of the Wikipedia Derangements article.

Comment: So my solution is correct right? and If you have another way please post.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is correct (see sequence A000166 in OEIS).

I like your proof in terms of it being elegant.  Your grammar isn't very good, but I don't see any logically more elegant way to prove that $R_n$ is the number of derangements of $n$ items.

Comment: Thanks, I will work on my grammar. This question was asked in our exam so just wanted to confirm my answer is correct or not. :)